# how to convert a local webapp to a standalone webkit app?

Tags: cocoa, web-applications, backbone.js, webview, webkit

I have a webapp that is designed to run locally (it doesn't need an internet connection to run, it just connects to a local websocket server). I would like to detach this app from the browser and have it run 'standalone', as if it was a native desktop app. Are there any tools to accomplish this? I would prefer a platform independent solution, but if not, how trivial would it be to port a local webapp to an (osx) cocoa app webview?

EDIT: not sure if it's relevant, but i'm using backbone.js/jquery and websockets.

Answer (score 0):

Appcelerator Titanium would be one platform you could do that with: http://www.appcelerator.com/platform/titanium-platform/

You might be able to use an Adobe Air model as well.